# Can we double encrypt VPN traffic with a custom certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, vpn, openvpn

I want to forward VPN traffic to an Internal Proxy that uses client certificates to authenticate users. Can we add this second encryption at the VPN Configuration file for example? Or what is the best option (architecture) to do that?
Thx a lot

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What benefit do you expect to get?

Comment: @MechMK1 we are using a managed VPN solution that does not offer auditing purposes, so we want to route all this VPN traffic over an HAProxy for example to inspect who is doing what

Comment: VPN works at the network level. Authentication against the proxy at the application level. Both can easily and transparently be stacked in each other: just access the HTTPS-speaking proxy which requires client certificate through the VPN.